# how deep in terms of access to resources should endpoints be designed

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

Let me explain in a very simple manner.

I am developing a school API. The resource schema is: A school can have program, a program an execution, an execution a module, a module assignments, which is owned by a student. How can I design a rest endpoint to access a student grades.

This is my proposal:
programs/:programId/executionmodules/:executionmodules/assigments/:assigmentsId/student/grades

Comment: url structure mostly exists for humans to easily understand, not automated clients. What is the issue with your proposal?

Comment: Well, the approach I want to develop. Is go as much nest it as need. The need can be considered from the wireframes in the front end and also when  querying in the db

Comment: Please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) stackoverflow guideline. This will help to scope your question better.

Comment: @JosueQuinteros is there such as thing as 'too much'? yes! When is that? I don't think you can set a hard rule. URLS are for humans and they are not useful for humans if they are 50 levels deep. So there is some line, but it's not a hard line. You need to decide when URLs are not useful and design them better.